# Order Isomorphism between $\omega_1$ and $\omega_1 \times \omega_1$

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

It is well known that $\omega_1$ and $\omega_1 \times \omega_1$ are order isomorphic when the latter is equipped with canonical well ordering. In fact, it can be explicitly given by $$\phi: \omega_1 \times \omega_1 \to \omega_1 $$ by
$(\alpha,\beta) \mapsto \text{order type of the initial segment generated by } (\alpha,\beta)$.

However, my question comes from an excerpt from M. E. Rudin's text $\textit{Lectures on set theoretic topology}$ where she is showing certain equivalent statements of $\diamondsuit$ which states

> there is a one to one function form $\omega_1$ onto $\omega_1 \times \omega_1$ which maps $\alpha$ onto $\alpha \times \alpha$ for each limit $\alpha$

I've tried proving that $\phi$ satisfies this property by inducting over over the limit ordinals, $\Lambda_{\omega_1}$, but can only seems to verify it for $0$.

Any tips or hints? Should  I try to find such a bijection that does not necessarily preserve order?

Edit: From the comments, it is now apparent that this $\phi$ will certainly not work. Then the question now shifts to: what exactly is this bijection which maps $\alpha$ onto $\alpha \times \alpha$ for all limit $\alpha$?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the $\phi$ in question already fails to have this property at $\alpha=\omega\cdot 2$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yep, I just noticed that it fails at $\omega$ even.

Comment: I think it holds at $\omega$? Each $(m,n)$ with $m,n$ finite gets mapped to a finite ordinal, unless I'm misunderstanding. (But I do think $\omega2$ is fatal.)

Comment: Oh yes, I'm very silly. Good catch!

Comment: You can use the fact that there is a nice and definable bijection from $\alpha$ to $L_\alpha$ for all infinite ordinals, and that $\alpha\times\alpha\subseteq L_\alpha$ for limit ordinals.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Here $L_{\alpha}$ is the $\alpha$th member in Godel's constructible hierarchy?

Comment: Yes. Although I find it hard to believe that this is what she meant.

Comment: Can't you just define the required bijection recursively?  Given a bijection from a limit ordinal $\alpha$ to $\alpha \times \alpha$, the next limit ordinal is $\beta = \alpha + \omega$.  Both $\beta \setminus \alpha$ and $(\beta \times \beta) \setminus (\alpha \times \alpha)$ are countably infinite, so match them up to extend the bijection.

Comment: @GoodMorningCaptain We have that $\omega_1^2\setminus(=\restriction\Lambda_{\omega_1})$ and $\omega_1\setminus \Lambda_{\omega_1}$ are both of cardinality $\omega_1$, just take any bijection between those 2, and add the bijection $g(\alpha)=(\alpha,\alpha)$ from $\Lambda_{\omega_1}$ to $=\restriction\Lambda_{\omega_1}$ (where $=\restriction A$ means $\{(x,x)\mid x\in A\}$)

Comment: Notice that the quoted sentence does not require the function to be order embedding

Comment: @DanVelleman: That would be too easy!

Comment: @ℋolo I think there is a subtlety being missed here (one that I certainly missed), but $\alpha \times \alpha$ is the initial segment given by $(0,\alpha)$. So, we need this bijection to have the property that given a limit $\alpha$, $f^{\rightarrow}(I_{\alpha}) = I_{(0,\alpha)}$ where $I_\beta$ is the initial segment generated by $\beta$. I don't believe that bijection will give this property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\phi : \omega_1 \to \omega_1 \times \omega_1$ is as described by Rudin.  Let $\alpha$ be any countable limit ordinal, and let $\beta = \alpha + \omega$.  Note that $\{\alpha\} \times \alpha$ is contained in $(\beta \times \beta) \setminus (\alpha \times \alpha)$, and therefore it must be contained in the image of $\beta \setminus \alpha$ under $\phi$.  Now let $f : \omega \to (\beta \setminus \alpha)$ be the bijection $f(n) = \alpha + n$.  Then there is a set $A \subseteq \omega$ such that $\phi \circ f \upharpoonright A$ is a bijection from $A$ to $\{\alpha\} \times \alpha$.  So if we let $g : \omega \to A$ be the enumeration of $A$ in increasing order and $h : \omega_1 \times \omega_1 \to \omega_1$ be projection onto the second coordinate, then $h \circ \phi \circ f \circ g$ is a bijection from $\omega$ to $\alpha$.  The upshot of this argument is that any such $\phi$ must encode bijections from $\omega$ to all countable limit ordinals.

Conversely, suppose that for each countable limit ordinal $\alpha$, $\phi_\alpha$ is a bijection from $\omega$ to $\alpha$.  For any limit ordinal $\alpha$, let $\beta = \alpha + \omega$.  Then it is not hard to use $\phi_\alpha$ to define a bijection from $\beta \setminus \alpha$ to $(\beta \times \beta) \setminus (\alpha \times \alpha)$.  Combining these bijections with a bijection from $\omega$ to $\omega \times \omega$ gives the required $\phi$ from $\omega_1$ to $\omega_1 \times \omega_1$.